# Why can't I test that a class's instance is defined

Tags: scalatest, playframework-2.6

I have a helper class which creates instance of another class

```
class TestEnv {
val questionsController = new QuestionsController(...)
}
```

I am unit testing `QuestionsController` and have created a basic test case

```
class QuestionsControllerUnitSpec extends PlaySpec with BeforeAndAfterAll with BeforeAndAfterEach with OneAppPerSuiteWithComponents{

  override def beforeEach() = {
    println("------------new test -----------------")
  }


  override def components: BuiltInComponents = new BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) with NoHttpFiltersComponents {

    import play.api.mvc.Results
    import play.api.routing.Router
    import play.api.routing.sird._


    lazy val router: Router = Router.from({
      case GET(p"/") => defaultActionBuilder {
        Results.Ok("success!")
      }
    })




  }

  "Question Controller " should {
    "be created" in {
      val testEnv = new TestEnv(components = components)
      val qc:QuestionsController = testEnv.questionsController
      qc mustBe defined //I get compilation error 

    }
  }


}
```

I get the following compilation error

```
Error:(52, 10) could not find implicit value for parameter definition: org.scalatest.enablers.Definition[controllers.QuestionsController]
      qc mustBe defined
Error:(52, 10) not enough arguments for method mustBe: (implicit definition: org.scalatest.enablers.Definition[controllers.QuestionsController])org.scalatest.Assertion.
Unspecified value parameter definition.
      qc mustBe defined
```

I checked the definition of `mustBe` in `MustMatchers.class`. It is defined as `def mustBe(right : org.scalatest.words.DefinedWord)(implicit definition : org.scalatest.enablers.Definition[T]) : org.scalatest.Assertion = { /* compiled code */ }`

Why am I getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`defined` matcher syntax can be used with user defined types if we provide implicit implementation of `Definition` trait. For example, say we have a user defined class

```
class Foo {
  val bar = 3
}
```

and we provide implicit definition

```
implicit val fooDefinition = new Definition[Foo] {
  override def isDefined(foo: Foo): Boolean = foo.bar != null
}
```

then we can use `defined` syntax

```
(new Foo()) mustBe defined
```

If similar implicit implementation of `Definition[QuestionsController]` is provided, then the compiler error should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I am happy to accept a different answer if it can provide more accurate answer. I suppose I am testing the wrong thing. What I am doing is similar to declaring an integer and checking if the integer exists! Instead I should be checking the value of the integer.

About `matchers`, more information is at http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/#org.scalatest.MustMatchers. More information on `Definition` is on http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/#org.scalatest.enablers.Definition